# Enable disable textbox

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disablefield() {
        if (document.getElementById('chkTaxApplicable').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('ddlTaxCode').value = '';
            document.getElementById('ddlTaxCode').disabled = false;
        }
        else 
         {
            document.getElementById('ddlTaxCode').disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my code.I want to enable the dropdown on checked=true and vice versa.
But i am not getting any output with this code.Should i use something better?

this is the html part using the above javascript.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTaxApplicable" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                             onclick="javascript:disablefield() " 
                                         />
                                        </td>

                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                   <td align="right" valign="middle" class="style41">Purchase Tax Code</td>
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" class="style42">:</td>
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" class="style43">
                                          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaxCode" runat="server" Enabled="False">
```

Comment: works great here: http://jsfiddle.net/HMU6h/1/

Comment: Your code works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/PNHRy/). Go ahead

Comment: Are you using `disablefield()` function in `onChange` event of `chkTaxApplicable` checkbox ?

Comment: i could enable the dropdown on click but when i click checkbox again it is not getting disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change some HTML/ASPX code

*First*

```
onchange = "disablefield(this)"
```

instead of

```
onclick="javascript:disablefield() "
```

You can pass `this` as a reference to your function where `this` will be the current object which is changed.

And in the javascript, You can handle `this` object like following.

```
function disablefield(elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
        document.getElementById('ddlTaxCode').value = '';
        document.getElementById('ddlTaxCode').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ddlTaxCode').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

If you're not using `this` as a reference then you have to use `.CliendID` as your checkbox is generated with server control [ASP Control].

So wherever the elements are of server controls you can try

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=chkTaxApplicable.ClientID%>') //Same way in textboxes
```

### [**Demo with `this` reference**](http://jsfiddle.net/PNHRy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `onchange="disablefield()"` instead of `onclick="javascript:disablefield() "`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

I think the problem is that you are not calling the disablefield() function.

> <input id="chkTaxApplicable" type="checkbox" onClick="disablefield();">

When giving javascript code, you should use this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net /hbCwe/2/

Edit:

It is because of javascript:disabledfield(); use disabledfield() instead, like above.

Answer (score 0):

you could use eventhandler.ie.

var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkTaxApplicable');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', disableField(), false);